# Good Scala pattern to consume from a Queue until there are no more messages?

Tags: scala, design-patterns, queue, akka

I have a queue of `N` messages dispatched by an Actor, I want to consume them all. The actor will return either a `Message` type or a `NoMessages` type if the queue is empty.

I came up with this but doesn't feel idiomatic, and I'm not sure about how many threads I'm spinning up every time I call `consume()`?

What is a better way of doing this?

```
def main(): Unit = {

  val queue = system.actorOf(...)

  def consume(): Unit = {
    ask(queue, Read) foreach {
      case Message(m) => {
        // handle message
        consume()
      }
      case NoMessages =>  {
        system.shutdown()
      }
    }
  }
  consume()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Message` and `NoMessages` extend a common trait (let's call it `Msg`), you could use [Akka Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/index.html):

```
import akka.Done
import akka.actor._
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

implicit val system = ActorSystem("QueueSys")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

val queue = system.actorOf(...)

def handleMessage(msg: Message): Unit = ???

implicit val askTimeout = Timeout(5.seconds)

val stream: Future[Done] = Source.fromIterator(() => Iterator.continually(Read))
  .ask[Msg](parallelism = 3)(queue) // adjust the parallelism as needed
  .takeWhile(_.isInstanceOf[Message])
  .runForeach(handleMessage)

stream.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

The above stream will continually send `Read` messages to the `queue` actor and process `Message` responses, until the actor replies with `NoMessage`.